# "Go To" and "Back To" in Google Docs API?

Tags: html, google-docs-api, presentation

How can I set a page, go to a next or go to the previous page in a Presentation of Google Docs using the Google Docs List API v3?, is possible to do them?.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to do that with the API.